# CoordinatorLayout pull down behaviour

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:expanded="false"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="I am some content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/z_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:title="I am the toolbar"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And it leads to the behaviour I want:

[image: Current Behaviour]

I specifically don't want the toolbar area to expand when I scroll in the middle of the list, hence I have omitted the enterAlways scroll flag. However, I have requirement that the toolbar itself can be pulled down and expanded at any point. How can I achieve this?